# Regex Operation to Extract html Strings

Tags: html, regex, web-scraping

I have the following html code:

```
'"height": { "@type": "QuantitativeValue", "value": "6-1" },\n    
"weight": {"@type": "QuantitativeValue", "value": "195 lbs" }\n}\n'
```

I want to create a Regex that'll extract the height and weight values (6-1 and 195 lbs). What re expression can do this?

Comment: What you posted above is not html code: it looks like a string resembling a dictionary, presumably part of some `script` tag? HTML is not parseable with regex. There are other parsers to be used for HTML. What is the page url?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus - Thanks for pointing this out, you are correct. This snippet is a string from a ```script``` tag that is from the html code of a website.

Comment: So can you confirm the url of the page in question?

Comment: https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/A/AbbrJa00.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have anything else with the pattern "value": "", then just use:

```
value":\s"?(.*)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/clWVkg/1

If you do, then you can specify that you only want the values from height and weight caught:

```
(height|weight).*"value":\s"?(.*)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/5ShdKO/1

This will check for the word `height` or `weight` first, then ignore everything until `value` before doing a lazy catch all to capture the value. You should be able to extract the value by extracting the group.

Comment: Could you include the command for the re operation? If the ```script``` is called raw, what command would extract the height and weight from it?